# :nth-child(even) selector by class with specific elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table that has a light gray background for the even rows and white for the odd ones. it works perfectly by using .tr:nth-child(even) {}

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr class="hidden"></tr>
    <tr class="hidden"></tr>
    <tr></tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: var(--bg);
}
```

I made a search field that filters table rows by adding `hidden` class for `tr` elements that not match after that the `tr:nth-child(even)` doesn't work.

I tried to add `search-result` class on the elements that match and then I made `tr:nth-of-type(even) { .... }`, also that not worked.

Is there any way that I can do that? for example, a way to select even elements by class?

Comment: Can you also share the css? And have you tried `opacity: 0` instead of not displaying it?

Comment: As I understand it, you are having trouble adding attributes to odd / even elements only after a search, when the other elements are hidden, correct?

Comment: @AksJacoves Yes, that's correct!

Comment: @Gh05d Updated with CSS code, If I used `opacity` there then I'll have a huge whitespace

Comment: Also add `height: 0`

Comment: @Gh05d `height: 0` and `opacity: 0` will act as the same with `display: none`, but it will not solve the current problem

Comment: The problem is that css will work with the existing elements, when you filter so that only some elements are displayed through the input (using for example display: none for those you don't want to display), these elements will still be in the document, so these table elements will continue in their even and odd ordering

Comment: Try tr:not(.hidden):nth-child(even)..

Comment: @AksJacoves Yeah this is the problem that I'm facing

Comment: @norcaljohnny tried but like **Aks Jacoves** said it will count the hidden elements too because they still exist in the document

Comment: You just need to remove the class hidden and change to a new class.. i do this all the time with filtered results.

Comment: are you using jquery or pure javascript? I will give a suggestion per answer

Comment: @AksJacoves Pure JS

Comment: Unfortunately the topic was closed, I will send a reply privately

Comment: Right here, see this example: codepen.io/aks-jacoves/pen/eYJZPoj?editors=1111

Comment: @MalikTürk Sorry for the delay but here is a simple functional example..Here is a link because i think it was wrongly closed. https://codepen.io/norcaljohnnyb/pen/WNrwqXJ

Comment: @norcaljohnny check this plz https://codepen.io/malikturk/pen/zYrqVJO, if you typed "ma" you will see that it will not works :/

Comment: @MalikTürk I just tried it and it works perfect. What browser are using?

Comment: @norcaljohnny chrome

Comment: @norcaljohnny if you typed "ma" then it will make the first two items with a grey background and this is not intended approach, odd rows should be just grey

Answer (score 0):

Fixed version of the codepen in the comments using a variant of the proof of concept I have at the bottom.  Count up indexes to check if even, excluding elements with display:none, done every update.  This may need to be optimized for very large tables.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("input");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("table");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
          td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
        txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
  //let table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0]
(function(){
let i = 0
table.querySelectorAll('tr:not(.hidden)').forEach(el =>
  el.style.display !== 'none' && i++ % 2 === 0 ? el.classList.add('even') : el.classList.remove('even'))
})()
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#input {
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
#table {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#table tr {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; 
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
}
#table th, #table td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}
#table tr :not(td) {
  background-color: #424242;
  color: white;
}
#table tr:not(.even) {
  background-color: #eee!important;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Adam</td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>malik</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Asal</td>
    <td>32</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Asal</td>
    <td>26</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Asali</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>malik</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>maaaalik</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

select non-hidden and use counter to find even.  add class.

```js
let table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0]

let i = 0
table.querySelectorAll('tr:not(.hidden)').forEach(el =>
  i++ % 2 === 0 && el.classList.add('even'))
```

```css
.even {
  background-color: red;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hidden">
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hidden">
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hidden">
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hidden">
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hidden">
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hidden">
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hidden">
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hidden">
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: not works, it counts `.hidden` elements

Comment: Right here, see this example: https://codepen.io/aks-jacoves/pen/eYJZPoj?editors=1111

Comment: I see it.  Made a mistake, it only resets after the first one.

Comment: You'll need JS, this one requires you to keep cascading CSS styles.  The other duplicate link has a jQuery solution

Comment: Sorry about that, mistook it.  Here's the simple JS solution of finding even indexes while excluding .hidden, another way without using the :not selector is to get all and use `.matches` to exclude .hidden elements from being counted